# PowerShell Get-ADUser with a local admin account

Tags: powershell, ldap

I'm trying to connect to a ldap server with PowerShell

In the LDAP browser, I specify an account, which seems to be a local admin account as "Other credentials"

[image: LdapConnection properties]

How can I do the same thing in PowerShell ?

I tried :

```
$c = Get-credential
user: directory manager
password for user directory manager : ****
$u = Get-ADUser -Server 192.168.1.1 -filter * -Credential $c
```

or

```
$c = Get-credential
user: cn=directory manager
password for user directory manager : ****
$u = Get-ADUser -Server 192.168.1.1 -filter * -Credential $c
```

But it doesn't work.

Have any ideas ?

Comment: What flavour of LDAP server? `Get-ADUser` only works with Active Directory

Comment: What do you mean by flavour ?
And how can I find this info ?

Comment: LDAP is a protocol - many different server implementations exist, of which Active Directory is just one. `cn=directory manager` is usually the name/rdn of the builtin manager account in OpenLDAP - another LDAP server that doesn't have anything to do with Active Directory.

Comment: If I guess it right it's Omnivista ?

Comment: If you have permission to AD, You can directly use Get-ADUser command,